# A sports wordpress website

Tags: custom-post-types, posts, custom-field

Hello wordpressers
Is there a way of joining custom post types?

One custom post type for **players** and another custom post type for **results**?

What i'm trying to do is use some post from the custom post type **players** on post from custom post type **results**, something like this:

man unt 2 - 1 valencia
i have to use players from custom post type **players**  to show the line up of Man Unt for example.

That way, i can use custom fields from cpt **players** as for example the picture of a player

i'll be wait for an answer. Thanks for your help :)

Answer (score 1):

Have you looked into this plugin?

http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/posts-to-posts/

Sounds a lot like what you need.

Comment: so do you thing this is tottaly possible with this plugin? thanks gold

Comment: Yes, although you probably need an additional post type for "clubs" to join them. The players would be attached to their clubs, and the clubs would be attached to the match results.